# Htaccess rewrite / redirect issue from .png.webp back to png

Tags: .htaccess

Can any experts in .htaccess tell me why this isn't working? (it's the last line that is key - the .png.webp to png rewrite) Please help!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.webp.png$ $1.png [L,R=301]
```

Example issue:

`https://centiqsap.com/wp-content/uploads-webpc/uploads/2020/07/Group-13-min-2.png.webp`

Needs to rewrite and redirect to

`https://centiqsap.com/wp-content/uploads-webpc/uploads/2020/07/Group-13-min-2.png`

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question(keep it up). Could you please post samples of your urls which is NOT working. Along with FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite? That will make your question more clearer, let us know, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment

Here is an example of a URL with the issue: https://centiqsap.com/service/accelerated-sustained-transformation/. As you can see, the images are not displaying. They have been converted to webp, however, the webp URLs do not exist. It's not a DB issue and I cannot locate the file causing the redirect (however, I think that it was Speed Kit).

Comment: Sorry, this is still not clear you need to mention which URL(sample details will work too) is not redirecting or rewriting correctly?

Comment: The image URL is https://centiqsap.com/wp-content/uploads-webpc/uploads/2020/07/Group-13-min-2.png.webp this needs to rewrite to https://centiqsap.com/wp-content/uploads-webpc/uploads/2020/07/Group-13-min-2.png

Comment: I've added the example to the question.

Comment: Looks like this is WP and you may have to use WP rewrite API for this

Comment: Your description of behavior and links to images should be written not as a comment, but in the body of your post because this is how other users could easily understand your question as a whole, without reading the comments

Answer (score 1):

Have your htaccess file like this way once(I have added new rule and kept OP's old rules too in rules file). Please make sure you clear your cache before testing your URLs. I have also fixed some minor issues, like your https redirection rule should be at very first and you should exacpe `.`(dots) in regex too.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test\.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*\.png)\.webp/?$ $1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.webp [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder. Unfortunately this doesn't work. Please can you visit Https://CentiqSap.com to check?

Comment: @NoviDigitalUK-SEOandPPC, you want to do redirection also so I have added R flag now for it, let me know how it goes?

Comment: Thank you, I shall try this.

Comment: Sadly no luck.
I have also tried.
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.webp$ $1?%{QUERY_STRING}

Comment: @NoviDigitalUK-SEOandPPC, are you seeing any error kindly share it with me

Comment: @NoviDigitalUK-SEOandPPC, I have edited the rules now, could you please do check now and let me know how its going?